# How to lift up whole screen when a TextFiled gained focus?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm desinging a screen using Scaffold in flutter where i have a AppBar and some TextFiled in body, now i want to lift up whole screen (including app bar) when TextFiled has gained focus and keyboard appears (because my bottom TextFiled got obscured by keyboard). I figured out how to detect foucs(using FocusNode) now only thing i want is to lift up whole screen when TextFiled gained foucs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true` to your Scaffold. By default the value is `true` which means it is resized the widget when keyboard comes up.

As mentioned you have multiple TextField in Scaffold then you can add `SingleChildScrollView` in body which will then scroll up if the Textfield if out of the viewport.

Example:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //Default is true so this can be ignore/removed
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Text Field 1')),
            TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Text Field 2')),
            TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Text Field 3')),
            TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Text Field 4')),
            TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Text Field 5')),
            TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Text Field 6')),
            TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Text Field 7')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```